# Making a fiveM Launcher

Tags: c#

Im trying to develop a Laucher to my FiveM server Right now i can open the FiveM from the appdata Local folder, but i need to insert the server ip to execute when the game start I visited the anser but i can't put it to work

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process p = new Path(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            //string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            System.Net.IPAddress ipaddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("http:127.0.0.1");
            //test, comment the next line out
            MessageBox.Show(System.IO.Path.Combine(appData, @"FiveM\test.exe" + ipaddress));
            p.StartInfo (@"FiveM\test.exe")                


        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you main question is how to start an external process with arguments. But your code won't compile for various reasons like using properties as Methods and assigning missmatching types. Have a look at the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2) on how to start an external process. If you then still struggle update your question with code that compiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a button that directly connects to the server IP that you put in you can do this.

```
private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("fivem://connect/185.113.141.24:30120");
}
```

Comment: When you click the button it direct connects to the server ip, in this case "185.113.141.24:30120"

Comment: now like this won't work, you need to set delay after execute about 2 second or will be error

Answer (score 0):

Here you're trying to convert a Path ("C:\ProgramData\YourProgram") to an Process. This won't work

```
Process p = new Path(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
//string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

Here You're creating an IP-Object.

```
System.Net.IPAddress ipaddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("http:127.0.0.1");
//test, comment the next line out
```

Here you're showing a messagebox with some text. `appData` is a variable which is out-commented.

```
MessageBox.Show(System.IO.Path.Combine(appData, @"FiveM\test.exe" + ipaddress));
```

Here you're trying to start a method `StartInfo()` which is a property.

```
p.StartInfo (@"FiveM\test.exe")
```

This realy is no working code.

**How to run an Exe? Try this:**

```
// Create some textfile in C:\Temp ..
string testFile = @"C:\Temp\test.txt";
using (File.Create(testFile))
{

}

// Choose the program to start. Path.Combine combines Paths, Directories and Filenames to one Path.
string path = Path.Combine(@"C:\Windows\System32", "notepad.exe");

// Your exe should have some arguments. In your case an IP-address i guess. If we start notepad we can tell him which file it should open.
string arguments = testFile;

// Start an exe with an argument
Process p = Process.Start(path, arguments);
// You would do the same if you push "Ctrl+R" and enter "C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe C:\Temp\test.txt"

// An now we tell our program to wait until the Process is closed..
p.WaitForExit();
```

If you want to continue programming. You should do some tutorials ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this as a button using the cfx.re code your server has.
It is similar to the first answer but opens their default browser and then proceeds to join.

```
Process.Start("cfx.re/join/aopp43");
```